# Save state of multiple Dynamic Components on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

Hi I have this component structure:

```
<ScheduleApp />
  <ScheduleForm />
    <TeamField />
```

My `ScheduleApp` contains a form called `ScheduleForm` and under this form I have a field where users can specify a number of teams and depends on the number the number of `TeamField` is created.

My form looks like this:

[image]

And what I wanted is to save all the teams' names under my `ScheduleApp` component. I can save all the other states with no problem, example: the `No. of Teams` field with no problem but I'm stuck on how to save the `Team Name` fields in an array.

Here is my poor attempt on saving the array but it looks like it saves all the keystrokes I've made probably because I triggered it `onChange` event.

[image]

How am I suppose to solve this problem and just save the dynamic components on the parent components' state?

Now here are my codes on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zug2krop/) for some reason I can't make it run on the site but will post it there for easier access.

Hope I made it clear. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing the current content of text box into the array on every change/keystroke. Instead what you should do is text box 1 should only modify the first index in your array. And text box 2 should only modify second field in your array and so on. On each change, replace entire content with new content.

Or a cleaner approach would be to store a teams object. And send a team number field too in the on change handler against which you can store the team name.

```
<input className="form-control" type="text" ref="teamName"
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(null, 'team1')} />  // pass any index or string instead of team1
...
handleChange(teamIndex, teamName) {
    let { teams } = this.state;
    teams[teamIndex] = teamName;
    this.setState({teams: teams};
}
```

Comment: Thank you heaps! I didn't think of this, now I realize how simple my problem is. By the way, I don't know what is the significance of the `key` on each component but can I use that instead of specifying the index? Can I use it in replacement to `teamIndex` based on your example?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children take a look at this link to see why we need a key tag. You can use the same value you assign to key.